# ActivityNotFound exception- Activity is declared

Tags: android

I have it so that when a user clicks on an item in the list view, they are taken to another activity which shows the item. However, when I test this, it throws an ActivityNotFound Exception even though I have clearly defined it in the manifest. This isn't happening for any other classes. Any ideas on how to fix? Here is the line that code that is causing the error, specifically the ctx.StartActivity...

```
listview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id ){
            xMessage = (String) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
            y = true;
            setView(xMessage,R.layout.messageclicked, R.id.mS);

            ctx.startActivity(new Intent(getActivity(),showMessage.class));

        }

    });
```

And here is the Manifest section where I declare the class:

```
<activity android:name = "com......showMessage" />
```

The...... is there to hide sensitive information. basically it is com.x.y.showRide, which is the correct file path for this Activity. Here is the manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="......."
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="11"
        android:targetSdkVersion="16" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.......SplashScreen"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:noHistory="true"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.........MainMenu"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" />
        <activity
            android:name="com........Register"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
            android:parentActivityName=".MainMenu"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/.....Theme" >
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value=".MainMenu" />
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com......SignIn"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
            android:parentActivityName=".MainMenu"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/......Theme" >
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value=".MainMenu" />
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="com......MainNavigation" />
        <activity android:name="com........MainScreen" />
        <activity android:name="com.......MainActivity" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.RuMad.......FindARide"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_find_aride" >
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".OfferRide"/>
        <activity android:name=".RequestRide"/>
        <activity android:name ="com......Compose"/>
        <activity android:name ="com.......IntendedUses"/>
        <activity android:name ="com.......showPreference"/>  
        <activity android:name = "com.......myRides"/>  
        <activity android:name = "com.......showMessage"/>
        <activity android:name ="com......OffRe"/>
        <activity android:name = "com......showRide" />    
        </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: can you show your full crash log and manifest file.

Comment: Tried with getApplicationContext() instead of getActivity()?

Comment: please send the code of yours current activity and manifest

Comment: amit, I'm not sure how to show my full crash log without posting a screen shot, and I can't do that because my reputation isn't high enough.

Comment: I'm not aware of problems when calling startActivity out of a fragment, but try to implement a callback-function from your fragment to the activity and then let the activity start the new activity

Comment: well in other fragments the startActivity works just fine, for some reason it just can't recognize the showMessage class

Comment: try cleaning your project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to solve this problem could be :

In your Activity that hosts this fragment,create some function, say

```
public void startShowMessageActivity(){
       Intent intent = new Intent(this, showMessage.class);
       startActivity(intent);
}
```

And in your fragment class, call this method using the Activity's context - ctx which I believe is (in your code)

So, essentially, say the Activity is MainActivity.java

```
(MainActivity(ctx)).startShowMessageActivity();
```

If the above statement doesn't work, try

```
MainActivity obj = (MainActivity)getActivity();
obj.startShowMessageActivity();
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: When I try to use your method it says that I need to make the method static but startActivity() can't be used in a static method because it is non-static

Comment: Okay..so what you could do is create an instance of MainActivity(MainActivity object = (MainActivity)getActivity) and then use this object to call the function. (object.startShowMessageActivity();)

Comment: also, edited the answer to include the above comment. Let me know if there are issues

Answer (score 0):

Suppose yours current activity is MainActivity than please use this line

```
startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity .this,showMessage.class))
```

Comment: are you sure? he's calling getActivity which is afaik only available in Fragments. So he tries to start the Activity out of a fragment

Comment: no i am not but just guess as he did not sent the ful code, even i request , please see the comments